# I want to capture audio for all VoIP applications such as Skype, G-Talk, Msn, etc

Tags: audio, sdk, capture, microphone, recorder

I need some links to record both microphone and audio in all the applications. I'm developing a audio recorder feature for an application.
I tried intercepting some APIs like IDirectSound and Wave API but I'm missing something since some applications are recorder and some others aren't.

Can someone send me a clue around this?

Best Regards.

Comment: Detours, and wrapping around waveOut* functions, maybe, or looking how does MxSkypeRecorder does it...  I would really love to see it working.

Comment: I know that application but I need something that I can use though my code. That is an standalone application for end users.

Comment: Yes, but it has a separate dll that is used to capture played audio.  Maybe with some reverse engineering you'll be able to find your way into its workings.  For example, list of exported functions (by name, if exists).

Comment: I just peeked into mxhook.dll, and it has very interesting strings at the end of the file...

Comment: Thank you for the information but if I can have something more straightforward it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my compary we've developed an [Audio Recorder SDK](http://internals.nektra.com/products/audio-recorder-sdk/) because it's very difficult to make all the hooks you need to intercept all the applications. You should hook MCI Wave API calls, IDirectSound interface and the new IAudioClient interface, part of the Windows Vista / Windows 7 Core Audio engine.
Our SDK supports Skype 4.x and 5.x, G-Talk and Msn. We've tested with other applications and it's working but we don't support them.
Additionally, we bring some UI features such as handling button clicks and get windows text using the SDK.

I hope this information can help you.

Comment: It's my best choise, I'll contact your company and test it how it works.

Comment: Shame, there is no documentation :3

Comment: Didn't you find the Trial version useful?